# Magento/Mailchimp integration, import fails

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento-1.7

I am currently trying to debug a syncronization process Magento -> Mailchimp, that does not work.
Ebizmarts/MageMonkey/etc/config.xml has this cron job-related configuration:

```
<magemonkey_bulksync_import_subscribers>
      <schedule><cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
      <run><model>monkey/cron::processImportJobs</model></run>
</magemonkey_bulksync_import_subscribers>
```

So the task is scheduled to be executed every hour.
Now, I can clearly see from a [script that I wrote](https://github.com/lorenzosfarra/scripts/blob/master/php/magento/check_cron.php) for my Magento store that the status of my task is "pending". Then, once the task is executed, the status becomes "success" with the message "Ebizmarts_MageMonkey_Model_Cron".
The problem is that the sync is **not** done.
So, to debug what happens, I've added some `Mage::log()` lines in the `processImportJobs`method, like this:

```
public function processImportJobs()
{
            $job = $this->_getJob('Import');
            Mage::log("importing");
            if(is_null($job)){
                    Mage::log("IS NULL!");
                    return $this;
            }
...
```

And if fact, I can see "importing IS NULL!" in the log, so this is why is not synced, I guess.
The `_getJob` method is:

```
    protected function _getJob($entity)
    {
            $job = Mage::getModel("monkey/bulksync{$entity}")
                                    ->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('IN' => array('idle', 'chunk_running') ))
                                    ->addOrder('created_at', 'asc')
                                    ->load();
            if(!$job->getFirstItem()->getId()){
                    return null;
            }

            return $job->getFirstItem();
    }
```

So it seems like my cron job status should be 'idle' or 'chunk_running' to be executed, and it's not.

Any hints?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the steps explained in Ebizmarts wiki? [How Can I sync subscribers in MailChimp with Magento](http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/magemonkey/faq#TOC-How-Can-I-sync-subscribers-in-MailChimp-with-Magento-)

Kind regards,
Santiago

Comment: thanks for your comment and sorry for the late response, I was trying to get additional info before replying :) Yes, I read that steps and the configuration should be fine, this is why I'm currently thinking that probably the problem is the other sense, exporting. In fact, in Newsletter -> MailChimp -> Bulk Sync -> Import, the number shown in the Magento list is not aligned with the real value. The cron job status of this task is "success", too. If I export the users manually and I add them manually, everything works fine. But probably I will have to open a dedicated thread.. updates soon :)

Comment: So after some tests with the Ebizmarts team and the MailChimp team, it SEEMS like it's an unexpected behavior depending on the MailChimp server. A MailChimp developer should now follow the problem and let me know something in the next days. Thanks anyway for your answer.